# Story ID: Early cyberpunk is restored with IQ-increasing drugs after a failed mission

Tags: story-identification

I'm guessing it is an 80s story or novellete.

The main character is a pretty unemotional mercenary.  After a failed mission he is put into the hospital, where the AIs there keep him alive, milking his bank account to pay for an experimental drug which later turns out to increase IQ.

After his account is empty, he's woken up and released, whereupon he goes back and finishes his earlier mission

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Videostar](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42561) by Walter Jon Williams.

The protagonist is Ric - I don't think we ever learn his surname. Ric is a member of a gang called the Cadillacs, and at the beginning of the story he goes into a meeting with other gang leaders:

> So there was a last meeting, Ric of the Cadillacs, Mares of the Squires, Jacob of the Last Men. Ric walked into the meeting with a radar-aimed dart gun built into the bottom of his briefcase, each dart filled with a toxin that would stop the heart in a matter of seconds. When he walked out it was with a money spike in his pocket, a stainless steel needle tipped with liquid crystal. In the heart of the crystal was data representing over eighty thousand Seven Moons dollars, ready for deposit into any electric account into which he could plug the needle.

But:

> He began to feel sick in the Tangier to Houston suborbital shuttle, a crawling across his nerves, pinpricks in the flesh. By the time he crossed the Houston port to take his domestic flight to L.A. there were stabbing pains in his joints and behind his eyes. He asked a flight attendant for aspirin and chased the pills with American whiskey.
> ...
> As they strapped him into a stretcher at the unscheduled stop in Flagstaff, Ric was still screaming, unable to stop himself. Jacob had poisoned him, using a neurotoxin that stripped away the myelin sheathing on his nerves, leaving them raw cords of agonized fiber. Ric had been in a hurry to finish his business and had only taken a single sip of his wine: that was the only thing that had saved him.

The drug is Genesios Three:

> Genesios Three was a new neurohormone, developed by the orbital Pink Blossom policorp, that could repair almost any amount of nerve damage. As a side effect it built additional neural connections in the brain, thus raising the IQ, and made people high.

and as you say the AI keeps Ric in hospital until his money is all gone:

> The week of Genesios therapy took fifteen thousand dollars out of Ric's spike.
>
>
> The previous months of treatment had accounted for another sixty-two thousand.
>
> What Ric didn't know was that Genesios therapy could have been started at once and saved him most of his funds, but that the artificial intelligences working for the hospital had tagged him as a suspect character, an alien of no particular standing, with no work history, no policorporate citizenship, and a large amount of cash in his breast pocket. The AIs concluded that Ric was in no position to complain, and they were right.
>
> Computers can't be sued for malpractice. The doctors followed their advice.